# jalopy source code formatter give Unhandled event loop exception when formatting

Tags: eclipse-juno, eclipse-indigo, jalopy

I have used eclipse Indigo and Juno to set up jalopy according to the  [jalopy installation guide](http://www.triemax.com/products/jalopy/manual/plugin-eclipse.html#plugin-eclipse-installation).My Jalopy version is 1.9.4. I can format the code in Indigo without any problem. But I can't format the code
in Juno. In error log view, I can see `Unhandled event loop exception` in `org.eclipse.ui` plugin, when I try to format the code in Juno.

this is the relevant exception stack trace

> org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.util.ConcurrentModificationException)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
>   Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>       at com.triemax.EclipsePlugin.l(EclipsePlugin.java)
>       at com.triemax.EclipsePlugin.a(EclipsePlugin.java:74)
>       at com.triemax.nu.run(nu.java:8)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
>       ... 24 more

what is the reason for this exception? how to prevent this?

**EDIT** :same exception arise in Eclipse Kepler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version you have is not compatible with Juno or Kepler. A more recent build fixes the problem.

Comment: can you post the official page that mention compatibilities?